# App that can use Mac hardware Volume buttons when set to Multi-Output

Tags: audio, macos, volume-control

There's a known quirk with macOS that if you set an output in Audio MIDI Setup to use a Multi-Output, you lose control of the dedicated volume buttons [on the F-Keys].

Is there an app that can override this limitation?

This would normally be achievable with Applescript & an Automator Service, but not if Multi-Output is selected.
You can't even change it from the optional Volume/Output Menu item. Volume is greyed out. Selecting anything except Multi-Output returns control. It doesn't matter which devices are selected in the Multi-Output itself, this is a limitation of the Multi-Output itself.

Free/paid, macOS [of course]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this app whilst searching for something else. I thought it would be worth including here for future searchers.

### [MultiSoundChanger](https://github.com/rlxone/MultiSoundChanger)

Freeware.

> A small tool for changing sound volume **even for aggregate devices*** cause native sound volume controller can't change volume of aggregate devices.
>
> Features:
>
> - Changing sound volume of every device (even virtual aggregate device volume by changing volume of every device in aggregate device)
> - Changing default output device
> - Native appearance (looks like native volume controller)
> - Media keys support

[image]

*It says aggregate, but it means Multi-Output [aggregates are actually Inputs] ;)